# Using ST_Union in PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, postgis-2.0

I have a spatial table (polygons,polylines) in a database. These are digitized by multiple people. For example, a state is divided into multiple Grids and given to multiple people to digitize using QGIS; which is connected to a postgres database. Now, I have to merge all those polygons and polylines.

I don't know how to do this via **ST_Union**.

I Used the following snippet to merge the polygons and polylines

```
CREATE TABLE schema_name.polygon_un2 AS
SELECT upg.un_geom,npg.Column1,npg.Column2,npg.Column3,npg.Column4,npg.Column5 
FROM (
 SELECT st_union(the_geom) As un_geom,(
  SELECT oid FROM schema_name.polygon 
  WHERE oid = 100748191 
 ) FROM schema_name.polygon WHERE oid IN (100748191,100763519) 
) upg 
INNER JOIN schema_name.polygon npg ON npg.oid = upg.oid; 

DELETE FROM schema_name.polygon WHERE oid IN (100748191,100763519);
```

I have the interesecting polygon oid in a Seperate Table, I want to do this process in an update query and that should be a dynamic plpgsql function.

[image: Here the Green Colour indicates the Grid and the other one indicates the Polygon.]

Green : Grid , Other : Polygon

But This snippet did not work !!

The snippet which i expect is

1. It should create a new row for the merged polygons and polylines (eg oid - 1 and 2 merged to oid 3).
2. The polygons which are not merged (eg 1 and 2 should be deleted)

Comment: Can you tell us what you already tried? Did you read the manual? What is the part that you don't understand. Be verbose!

Comment: Have you enabled PostGIS on the PostgreSQL database? PostgreSQL does not automatically have spatial capabilities within it. Editing your question with more information as @tilt recommended will help others help you.

Comment: @jbukoski, I have added more description regarding the question and obviously i have enabled postgis extension...!!

Comment: @tilt I ahve added the snippet which i used. Thanks for you kind Reply...

Comment: Additional Information : The polygons and polylines at the intersection near the grid line are checked for snapping,Slivers,overlap,multi-part,duplicate and null geometries and everything has been fixed ,Merging has to be done and As the polygons and polylines does not have a common attribute to merge via ST_Union ,I am Struggling as Group by (some column name) is not possible.

Comment: I still don't understand what the problem is, you only say that it doesn't work but there is no error message or unexpected output. Also, I don't understand why you add the oid in your query with: `SELECT oid FROM schema_name.polygon WHERE oid = 100748191 `

Comment: Thanks for your time @tilt,I fixed it. But the issue is 1. I don't have any columns to group it like `Select st_union(the_geom) from table group by oid `    So  i was not able to merge all the polygons at a time. Now i have created a column for grouping and it is done... Thank you by the way for your valuable time.

Comment: @Deepan Kaviarasu you could create a answer to you own question. took me a while to find your resolving comment.