# How to properly use JOIN or GROUP By for ST_Union in PostgreSQL with PostGIS extension

Tags: postgis, raster, postgresql, clip

There was already a [related question,](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247604/how-to-use-st-union-in-postgresql) but it is not answered yet and doesn't provide the necessary information for this case...

I want to cut a raster with a polygon. The raster is stored in tiles in the PostGIS database, as is the polygon.

[image: This is the data.]

To find out the overlapping areas I wanted to use `ST_Clip` or `ST_Intersection`. Since the raster is stored in tiles and no empty raster should be returned, I want to join the tiles of the raster with `ST_Union` first and then apply `ST_Clip` or `ST_Intersection`.

The problem is that there is not enough information on the PostGIS website about the syntax of these functions or about further necessary steps.

Version 1:

```
SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_Clip (ST_Union(landcover_raster.rast), polygon.geom),3035) 
FROM landcover_raster, polygon;
```

Version 2:

```
WITH raster_together AS( ST_Union (rast) FROM landcover_raster) 
SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_Clip (raster_all, polygon.geom)),3035) 
FROM landcover_ausschnitt_polygon;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are going to want to add the spatial join condition of st_intersects for these two tables to more efficiently run the query. your two attempts use an implicit cross join which is not the right join for this query

```
select  ST_SetSRID(st_union(st_clip(landcover_raster.rast, polygon.geom)),3035) rast
FROM landcover_raster join polygon on ST_Intersects(landcover_raster.rast, polygon.geom)
```

Comment: So what kind of join is it you are using instead?

Comment: With thin query the Error: "missing FROM-clause entry for table "landcover_raster". Maybe some more information would help me to fix the error..? :)

Comment: Try again- i had from in there twice

Comment: On st_intersects- this is a spatial join. Will only selected records from each table where they spatially intersect

Comment: I left out the 'FROM' already. Do you have any other ideas what the Problem could be?

Comment: Here (https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Union.html) I found this Example: 

SELECT ST_Union(rast)
FROM aerials.boston
WHERE ST_Intersects(rast,  ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(230486 887771, 230500 88772)',26986) );

Which kind of worked, even though I had to recreate the polygon I intersect with. 
But I'm still open for improvement ideas :)

Comment: my query will get you your answer. copy and paste the query again i initiatly had an extra from in there